# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type, but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is what I am trying to do. I don't understand Why it is expecting an enumerable list.

AddressController.cs

```
public ActionResult ShowAddresses(List<Address> ReturnAddresses)
    {
        ShowAddressViewModel viewModel = new ShowAddressViewModel() { Addresses = ReturnAddresses, Message = "New" };
return PartialView("_ShowAddr", viewModel);
```

}

ShowAddressViewModel.cs

```
public class ShowAddressViewModel
{
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

_ShowAddr.cshtml

```
@model PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<form>
<div class="addressBlock">
<table id="AddressTable">
    @{int i = 0;}
     @{PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel AddrModel = Model;}
    @foreach (var item  in AddrModel.Addresses)
    {
        <tr id = "@(i)">
            <td>@(AddrModel.Addresses[i].Address1)
            </td>
            <td>@(AddrModel.Addresses[i].Address2)
            </td>
            <td>@(AddrModel.Addresses[i].City)
            </td>
            <td>@(AddrModel.Addresses[i].State)
            </td>
            <td>@(AddrModel.Addresses[i].Zip)
            </td>
        </tr>
        @(i++)
    }
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

edit

Call from Another partial view's java script

```
$.ajax(url, {
            data: { ReturnAddresses : InboundAddresses },
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
                //Populate the form values
                // Start Dialog Code
                $myWindow = jQuery('#myDiv');
                //instantiate the dialog
                $myWindow.html(data);
                $myWindow.dialog({
                    title: 'Select an address',
                    modal: true,
                    width: 'auto'
                });
                $myWindow.show();
                $myWindow.dialog("open");
                // End Dialog Code

                $('#AddressTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                    alert('You clicked row ' + ($(this).index()));
                });
                addAddress(Addresses, Message)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#Message').val('Kaboom!!! (The call blew up...#thatsucks)');
                alert('The Dialog Box call failed...Sorry :(');
            }
        });
    }
```

Server Error in '/PSPOC' Application.
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel]'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel]'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  


Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel]'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +383
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +625
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +138
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +727120
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +727076
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +334
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +52
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044
```

Comment: Whereabouts are you getting this error - in the foreach in the Razor file? And why are you using `AddrModel.Addresses[i].City` rather than just `item.City` etc.

Comment: And should your `@(i++)` have curly braces not round brackets? (guessing from the other code, I've never used Razor)

Comment: @Rup Look at `<tr id="@(i)">`

Comment: I am calling this method from another partial view's javascript which is returning a Internal server error 500. I am new to MVC or anything related to C# for that matter. I got the error message from fiddler. All the razor script I have to make changes. But, even if I take out all the razor script, I still got that error

Comment: Set your action to be of type PartialViewResult instead of ActionResult. Also, please show the call to the action, are you using RenderAction?...

Comment: OK, but if you're seeing the 'yellow screen of death' in fiddler then it should include a stacktrace too?

Comment: I believe your problem comes in the request of this action, not in the rendering of this view. Maybe try posting the javascript that makes this call.

Comment: @LarsAnundskås I tried using PartialViewResult  and I got the same response back. I am using Ajax call. Please see the initial question - I added the call.

Comment: @Rup I added the trace now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to render your view with

```
@Html.Partial("_ShowAddr", Model.Adr)
```

And your model are sent to the view without going through the controller, so you are actually sending the view a collection of addresses instead of the wrapped viewmodel.

Try this approach instead:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("ShowAddresses", Model.Adr); }
```

**EDIT**

Actually:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("TestPart", new { ReturnAddresses = Model.Adr }); }
```

Comment: I am not using razor to render the page. Please see my javascript on how I am using the returned partial view.

Comment: how does the post look like if you inspect in fiddler/firebug, what is the contents of data: { ReturnAddresses : InboundAddresses },

Comment: Lars, Rebuilding the project made it start working. I don't know what happened. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it. To answer your question, InboundAddresses is an array of address objects. an address object is defined locally and consists of address information.

Answer (score 0):

i think is

```html
return PartialView("_ShowAddr", viewModel.ToList());
```

And in the top of your `_ShowAddr.cshtml`

```html
@model IEnumerable<PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Models.ShowAddressViewModel>
```

im doing something like you